# jQuery JSON AJAX Error on Returned Data

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, json, select

I want to create a dynamic select input (dropdown menu) from JSON.

I have tried two approaches to getting a JSON object for a dropdown menu Select input (which I have labeled Attempt 1 and Attempt 2 in the commented out JS).

I have the string returning to the client, however, the front end is not seeing it as a JSON object, but rather just a string. I have tried to parse and serialize it using both the .Net serializer and the Json2 Parse.

AJAX Call

```
function getcategories(categoryId) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Services/Category.aspx/GetCategory',
        data: '{"categoryId":"' + categoryId + '"}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        global: false,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d == null || msg.d == '') {
                //end of the road. not more categories. so don't add another DDL
                jsonList = '';
                console.log("No more DDLs: ");
            } else {
                //attempt 1: converting returned data to Json
                //var json = JSON.parse(msg.d);//just returns [object object]
                //jsonList = json.d;
                //attemp2: trying to consume stringbuilder string as Json
                //or if I do the below, I also get an error Table does not exist
                //jsonList = msg.d
            }
        }

    });
    return false;

}
```

Returned JSON

```
{
    "Table": [{
        "categoryid": "0",
        "categoryname": "--Select Category1--"
    }, {
        "categoryid": "2",
        "categoryname": "subname2"
    }, {
        "categoryid": "3",
        "categoryname": "subname3"
    }, {
        "categoryid": "4",
        "categoryname": "subname4"
    }]
}
```

Trying to use it in a loop here:

```
//simplified function inside the ready()
//add dynamic select with options from Json
$('<select id ="DDL' + nextSelect + '" class="cascade"><option value="-">-- Step' + nextSelect + ' --</option></select>').appendTo('div .chooseSteps');
console.log("Obj " + categoryJson); //shows the Json string 
console.log("TABLE " + categoryJson.Table); //returns undefined :(
var listItems = "";

//Says that Table does not exist (undefined)
for (var i = 0; i < categoryJson.Table.length; i++) {
    listItems += "<option value='" + categoryJson.Table[i].categoryid + "'>" + categoryJson.Table[i].categoryname + "</option>";
}
```

So my goal is to get the options to display and get the values of Table.

I searched the forum all afternoon, and could not find a solution that worked, and this is driving me crazy. Thanks for your understanding.

I am using jQuery 1.7.1 AJAX with Json2.js (as a backup for older browsers) with Asp.Net 4.

Comment: have you been through this stuff? http://encosia.com/jquery-for-the-asp-net-developer/

Comment: Is the returned JSON the real JSON or just what you are expecting? Should be wrapped in {"d":{} }

Comment: @chris vdp the msg object has the d wrapper. Inside d is the string listed above. I have been through those Encosia pages and many of the other responses here on SA but nothing yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response doesn't have a `d` property.

Don't try to parse it. jQuery does that.

Just do this:

```
jsonList = msg.Table
```

Although I don't see where you're transitioning from the AJAX call to the code at the bottom, so I'm not sure what's happening in between.

These suggest the JSON isn't parsed:

```
console.log("Obj " + categoryJson); //shows the Json string 
console.log("TABLE " + categoryJson.Table); //returns undefined :(
```

So right here you would need to `$.parseJSON` it. Again, I see no relationship between the two code examples.

Comment: .net wraps all responses in d. Have a feeling it's not the real JSON return

Comment: Hello, Yes msg.d is the data of the object and it is not a real Json return except that I added [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] in the hope that it would do something. I do get a string back and the string I listed above is the result of msg.d

Comment: @User970008: If `msg.d` gives you the JSON string, then `JSON.parse(msg.d);` should take care of you. The fact that it gives you `[object Object]` shouldn't be a concern. That's just the `toString` value of an Object. you should still be able to access its properties.

Comment: `var json = JSON.parse(msg.d); json.Table[0].categoryname` should work.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using $.parseJSON instead of JSON2.js:
 
 categoryJson = $.parseJSON(msg.d);

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seem that you need to call: msg.Table and not msg.d... msg.d seems to be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through javascript objects with jquery.each

html

```
<select id="fillme"></select>​
```

javascript

```
var categoryJson = {"Table":[{ "categoryid":"0","categoryname": "--Select Category1--             
"},{"categoryid":"2","categoryname":"subname2"},
{"categoryid":"3","categoryname":"subname3"},
{"categoryid":"4","categoryname":"subname4"}]};

var table = categoryJson.Table;

$(table).each(function(key,cat){
    var option = '<option value="'+cat.categoryid+'">'+cat.categoryname+'</option>';
    $('#fillme').append(option);
});
```

[jquery example what this code do](http://jsfiddle.net/BwMQH/1/)

Comment: I get an "unrecognized expression" error when I try this method. I think the issue is that the returned data is a flat string and not an object.